# Django filter JSONField list of dicts

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset, django-jsonfield

I run Django 1.9 with the new JSONField and have the following Test model :

```
class Test(TimeStampedModel):
    actions = JSONField()
```

Let's say the action JSONField looks like this :

```
[
  {
    "fixed_key_1": "foo1",
    "fixed_key_2": {
      "random_key_1": "bar1",
      "random_key_2": "bar2",
    }
  },
  {
    "fixed_key_1": "foo2",
    "fixed_key_2": {
      "random_key_3": "bar2",
      "random_key_4": "bar3",
    }
  }
]
```

I want to be able to filter the foo1 and foo2 keys for every item of the list.
When I do :

```
>>> Test.objects.filter(actions__1__fixed_key_1="foo2")
```

The Test is in the queryset. But when I do :

```
>>> Test.objects.filter(actions__0__fixed_key_1="foo2")
```

It isn't, which makes sense. I want to do something like :

```
>>> Test.objects.filter(actions__values__fixed_key_1="foo2")
```

Or

```
>>> Test.objects.filter(actions__values__fixed_key_2__values__contains="bar3")
```

And have the Test in the queryset.

Any idea if this can be done and how ?

Answer (score 34):

If you wan't to filter your data by one of fields in your array of dicts, you can try this query:

```
Test.objects.filter(actions__contains=[{'fixed_key_1': 'foo2'}])
```

It will list all `Test` objects that have at least one object in `actions` field that contains key `fixed_key_1` of value `foo2`.

Also it should work for nested lookup, even if you don't know actual indexes:

```
Test(actions=[
    {'fixed_key_1': 'foo4', 'fixed_key_3': [
        {'key1': 'foo2'},
    ]}
}).save()

Test.objects.filter(actions__contains=[{'fixed_key_3': [{'key1': 'foo2'}]}])
```

In simple words, contains will ignore everything else.

Unfortunately, if nested element is an object, you must know key name. Lookup by value won't work in that case.

Comment: While trying the first one, I got this error:- `TypeError: Lookup type 'contains' not supported with list argument`, which got reduced by manipulating query as `Test.objects.filter(actions__contains={'fixed_key_1': 'foo2'})`

Answer (score 11):

You should be able to use a `__contains` lookup for this and pass queried values as list as documented [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#contains). The lookup would behave exactly like ArrayField. So, something like this should work:

```
Test.objects.filter(actions__contains=[{'fixed_key_1': 'foo2'}])
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [django-jsonfield](https://github.com/bradjasper/django-jsonfield) package, I guess it's already the one you are using.

```
from jsonfield import JSONField
class Test(TimeStampedModel):
    actions = JSONField()
```

So to search to make a search with a specific property, you can just do this:

```
def test_filter(**kwargs):
    result = Test.objects.filter(actions__contains=kwargs)
    return result
```

If you are using PostgreSQL, maybe you can take advantage of PostgreSQL [specific model fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/postgres/#module-django.contrib.postgres).

PS: If you are dealing with a lot of JSON structure you have maybe to consider using NoSQL Database.

Comment: I'm actually already using PostgreSQL's JSONField specific model field (`from django.contrib.postgres.fields import JSONField`). Your solution works when `your_property` is known (`fixed_key_1` and `fixed_key_2` in my case) but how can I do when I don't know `your_property` (`random_key_#` in my case) ?

Comment: You should make `{'fixed_key_1': 'foo2'}` your paramter, I updated the code with generic function.

Comment: The thing is I don't especially know `your_property`. It could be anything and I don't even care about it, just want to know if the JSONField contains a given string in any of its values, regardless the depth.

Comment: Yes as I explained, you can insert whatever variable to the `test_filter` method and if the result is an empty list, this means it does not contain the given parameter, otherwise the list will be not be empty and this means it contains the variable.

Comment: Could you please give an exemple of what you would insert to your `test_filter` method to see if `"bar3"` is contained anywhere in the JSONField, knowing that you **don't know** any key except `fixed_key_1` and `fixed_key_2` ? 'Cause I don't think that we're talking about the same problem.

Comment: `Test.objects.filter(actions__contains="bar3")` should work.

Comment: This doesn't work. It says that this is not a valid syntax for the json type.