# Django Postgres JSONField query

Tags: django, python-3.x, postgresql, django-rest-framework

I have a class with a json field in it

```
class A(models.Model)
    brand = JSONField()
```

If I post an array of JSON like [{'brand_id:1', 'name':'b1'}, {'brand_id:2', 'name':'b2'}] it is stored as an array of JSON. This works fine.

How should I query so as to check if '1' is present in the brand_id of any dictionary in that array?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django filter JSONField list of dicts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34358278/django-filter-jsonfield-list-of-dicts)

Answer (score 5):

Well first of all your JSON here is malformed. I presume it is meant to be:

```
[{'brand_id': 1, 'name': 'b1'}, {'brand_id': 2, 'name': 'b2'}]
```

If that's the case, to test for `1` in such a blob, something like this will tell you if `1` is to be found *anywhere* in the JSON as a value:

```
def check_for_one(json_data):
    return any([1 in data.values() for data in json_data])
```

But you want to know specifically if `1` is a value owned by a key 
`brand_id` anywhere in the JSON so you can also use a loop to add in some extra conditions:

```
def check_for_one(json_data):
    match = []
    for data in json_data:
        for key, value in data.items():
            if key == 'brand_id' and value == 1:
                match.append(True)
    return any(match)
```

You can incorporate such logic as methods on your model class like this:

```
class A(models.Model):
    brand = JSONField()

    def check_for_one_comprehension(self):
        return any([1 in data.values() for data in self.brand])

    def check_for_one_loop(self):
        match = []
        for data in self.brand:
            for key, value in data.items():
                if key == 'brand_id' and value == 1:
                    match.append(True)
        return any(match)
```

But, if you actually want to filter instances from the database where the JSON data is an array at the top level and `brand_id == 1`, that needs a different approach, and this should do it:

```
A.objects.filter(brand__contains=[{'brand_id': 1}])
```

Note the additional `[{}]` braces! If you just call `contains=['brand_id': 1]` it will throw a syntax error and if you call `contains={'brand_id': 1}` it will not match.

Comment: Can you explain why brand__contains=[{'brand_id': 1}] works but brand__contains={'brand_id': 1} does not?

Comment: Because `contains={'brand_id': 1}` is not taking account of the fact it needs to filter through the top-level *list* we have with the json shaped like: `brand = [{'brand_id': 1, 'name': 'b1'}, {'brand_id': 2, 'name': 'b2'}] `. If the json was shaped like `brand = {'brand_id': 1, 'name': 'b1'}`, then it would match.

Comment: Very helpful. Note that if the JSON structure is not a list (e.g., `{'brand_id: 1}`, no `[]`s), then you don't need the `[]`s in python.

Answer (score 2):

This worked:

```
A.objects.filter(brands__contains=[{'brand_id':1}])
```

I didnt check it first by using the array.
Link pointed put by @Bear Brown gives sufficient info.
Its easy in django, but finding it out took time :P.

Comment: This does not work if the JSON Field stores an array.

Comment: @rtindru not true, you can filter through a json array but you would need the `{}` in this case to cast the key and value correctly. `['brand_id':1]` will throw a syntax error.

Comment: @jhrr True; the code above raises a `SyntaxError`. Can you describe how the filter would work inside the JSON field if the field stores a JSON array?

Comment: @rtindru I have put the correct version in my main answer above. See the very end of that.

Comment: Works like a charm; my mistake. I was missing the array notation. Can you explain why `brand__contains=[{'brand_id': 1}]` works but `brand__contains={'brand_id': 1}` does not?