# Django JsonField filter by two fields

Tags: django, django-jsonfield

```
class Blog:
   values = JSONField(blank=True, default=list)
```

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "value": "31"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "value": "Hello"
  },
  ...
]
```

I need to get all objects where the id is 1 and value of that field is greater than 31.
I have tried `q = queryset.filter(values__0__id=1, values__0__value_gte=31)` but it works only for objects if an object that I need located only in first element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently, nowadays `Django` has not built-in support for array elements comparison for `JSONField`. Fortunately, `Django` allows to make a lot of custom staff. For example, `Django`'s [raw SQL](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/sql/#django.db.models.Manager.raw) feature.

And if you use PostgreSQL as your main DB, you can use [JSON Processing Functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-PROCESSING-TABLE). The `jsonb_array_elements()` from JSON processing functions is pretty nice choice.

Combining features above, we can make a little workaround for your case:

```
# Create method that uses raw SQL within your `objects` Model Manager.
# Create your own filters as you want. This example should be improved
# and handle exception cases of course.
def filter_blogs_json(json_field, sql_operator, value):
    return Blog.objects.raw(f"SELECT id, data FROM yourappname_blog CROSS JOIN jsonb_array_elements(values) AS data WHERE (data->'{json_field}')::numeric {sql_operator} {value};")

# You can get raw objects queryset 
raw_blogs_qs = filter_blogs_json('value', '>=', 31)

# Then you can process it anyway you want
filtered_blog_ids = [b.id for b in raw_blogs_qs]
queryset = Blog.objects.filter(...).filter(id__in=filtered_blog_ids)
```

Pretty easy, isn't it? :)

Moreover, I believe it is possible to make your own queryset [Lookup](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/db/models/fields/json.py)'s for `JSONField`, extend queries as you want and etc.

Answer (score 0):

Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow!

Try looking at Django's Q objects. Some documentation is available [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects).

### Case 1

As mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35366946/6241823) answer, try using the `__contains` filter:

```py
Blog.objects.filter(values__contains=[{'id': 1}])
```

and then manually filter the results for the second field.

### Case 2

Perhaps a better option would be to have a second table for the individual values, like the following models:

```py
class Blog(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)  # or something else


class Value(models.Model):
    blog = models.ForeignKey(Blog, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    json = models.JSONField(blank=True, related_name="values")
```

and then perform the search like so:

```py
Blog.objects.filter(Q(values__json__id=1) & Q(values__json__value__gte=31))
```

Comment: Your case work if and only if JSONField(default=dict), but in my case is list of dict

Comment: @YelibayNuptebek in the first case it should look into the list. The second case is a cleaner way to accomplish the same thing, just breaking the JSON list into multiple DB rows only containing a JSON dict.

Comment: what is your first case and second case? describe @MichalKrejčí

Comment: @MichalKrejčí it does not work for this case, `Blog.objects.filter(Q(values__json__id=1) & Q(values__json__value__gte=31))` work onlu of JsonField contain only json, but in this case is list of dict