# How do I write a Django query that searches a nested JSON array?

Tags: json, django, postgresql, django-queryset

I have the following JSON object (named 'data') on my Draft model:

```
DRAFT1 data=
{
    communications = [
                        {name: "john"},
                        {name: "bobby"}
                     ]
}


DRAFT2 data=
{
    communications = [
                        {name: "mark"},
                        {name: "erin"}
                     ]
}
```

I'm guessing this is vaguely correct for a query, but I can't figure out the syntax for the '*'?

Draft.objects.filter(data__communications__*__name__in=['john', 'erin']).count()

How can I write a Django/Postgres query to return DRAFT1 and DRAFT2 as the result?

Comment: did you find a solution?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34358278/django-filter-jsonfield-list-of-dicts

Answer (score 0):

You can use the contains lookup to find the names within the communications arrays, and use "|" to grab both.

```
Draft.objects.filter(
    Q(data__commitments__contains={"name": "john"}) |
    Q(data__commitments__contains={"name": "erin"})
).distinct()
```

Comment: data is a JSON object and data.commitments contains a JSON array nested within there. This syntax doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry. Still not working. My data.commitments = [ {"name": "john" ....}].  There are many elements in the Object, to which I don't have all their values.

Answer (score 0):

in case anyone is struggling with this, i found a helpful answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34358278/django-filter-jsonfield-list-of-dicts)

so in your case, it'll be something like

`Draft.objects.filter(data__communications__contains=[{"name":"erin"}])`